# How to I change alignment of a single page in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice

I can change the alignment of a page in OpenOffice, but it affects all pages.

Any ideas how this can be done for a single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone! See this Open Office [forum answer](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=29461) that seems to cover your requirements by use of page breaks.